# DMA from Linux kernel-space to PCIe card

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma, pci, pci-e

I am trying to write a linux driver for a PCIe device - the Adlink PCIe 7300A High-Speed digital-IO card.

The driver works fine for normal memory transfer, but attempting to use the card's bus-mastering capabilities to initiate DMA transfer of a buffer from CPU memory to the device's output FIFO buffer simply does not work.

I have been trying to solve this problem on the order of weeks, not on the order of days.

Any insight at all would really really be appreciated.

Driver code -- https://github.com/sbrookes/timing_driver_sdarn/blob/master/kernel_land/timing.c

Device Datasheet -- http://www.acceed.com/manuals/adlink/P7300A%20Manual.PDF

PLX 9080 PCI Interface chip Datasheet -- http://www.der-ingo.de/bin/milanhelp/PLX9080.pdf

I can not explain how much I would appreciate any bit of insight.

Thank you,

Scott

Comment: That driver is horribly buggy all over, but SO is not the correct site for code reviews. Anyway, what is the value of `dma_bus_addr`?

Comment: @CL. - Sorry if I am polluting SO with bad questions. I don't know where else to turn.

Comment: @CL. - Didn't mean to submit that so soon... anyway `dma_virt_addr = pci_alloc_consistent(dev, 20*1024, &dma_bus_addr); printk(KERN_DEBUG "dma_bus_addr is 0x%x\n", dma_bus_addr);` reports **dma_bus_addr is 0x2c538000** but I don't know that this is the same each time I load the module... I want to play nice on this site, tell me what I can do to make sure of that? I can not explain how much I appreciate your help. Interested in all bugs as well as "best practices" too, btw. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't `dma_addr_t` a 64-bit value?

Comment: @CL. My card only has a 32 bit register for the destination address. So even if it is 64 bits the printk is trimming the leading zeros I think.

Comment: What is the value output with `%llx`?

Comment: @CL. From new run -- **dma_bus_addr is 0x47b98000, dma_bus_addr w/ new format specifier is 0x   47b98000** (three spaces between 0x and 47...)

Comment: Are you running on a 32-bit kernel?

Comment: `uname -m` prints **x86_64** so it seems like I am working on a 64 bit kernel.

Comment: @CL. forgot to ping you on that response... I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You should not try to set a 64-bit DMA mask if your device cannot do 64-bit DMA transfers. (You are lucky that your code to set a 64-bit mask is buggy.)

Comment: As for your problem, "does not work" is rather vague. The code for allocating coherent DMA memory looks correct; the problem may be with programming one of the chips you're using. You should check the PLX9080 register to see whether the DMA transfer did actually run.

Comment: @CL. Ok, I'll look into the DMA masks. I misunderstood the documentation. Thanks again for your time. But where should I look for the bugs?

Comment: @CL. The reason that I am so desperate is that I have no way to get any further information about the problem! I tell the DMA transfer to start (by writing to regs on the 9080) and then nothing happens. The PLX9080 status register never says that it is busy or anything... I don't know how to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Try to look at another PLX9080 driver (such as the staging comedi driver).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem. It seems like there was an incorrect condition in the interrupt handler that was aborting the DMA transfer at the wrong time, never letting the transfer even begin.

A serious "duh"  moment, but it took serious struggle to find it.

As per the comments, sorry if I polluted SO with my desperation. Still learning how to be a good citizen.

Not sure if the code linked above will remain static as my project changes or whether that link will reflect the most current version. Basically just be careful not to abort your transfer at the wrong time.